# RXJS accumulation

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm receiving history frame from a bluetooth device and I would like to re-compute history on each frame.

I can have that kind of history object:

```
{
  value1: [
    { date: new Date(), value: 45}
    { date: new Date(), value: 40}
  ],
  value2: [
    { date: new Date(), value: true}
    { date: new Date(), value: false}
  ]
}
```

Now sometime I receive new Data as example

```
{
  value1: [
    { date: new Date(), value: 60}
  ],
}
```

And I would like to get

```
{
  value1: [
    { date: new Date(), value: 60}
    { date: new Date(), value: 45}
    { date: new Date(), value: 40}
  ],
  value2: [
    { date: new Date(), value: true}
    { date: new Date(), value: false}
  ]
}
```

I've started by writing this, but I'm not sure if there is not an operator for that already…

```
  RX.pipe(
        filter(frame => FrameTypes[frame.FrameType] === FrameTypes.HIST),
        scan((acc, val) => {
          // Merge data by hand (not done already)
        }, historyFromDatabase),
      ).subscribe(fullHistory => {
        console.log(fullHistory);
        // Update history to only keep values from the last two weeks
        const newHistory = cleanOldData(2, history)
        // Now save new history to database with previous and new values.
        saveHistory(newHistory)
      });
    }
```

Do you have better idea how can I achieve that?

Regards,
Andréas

Comment: I think `scan` is really what you're looking for. There's no operator that would merge the data for you. I'm sure lodash has some function for that already so you won't have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In case your `Observable` is finite (explanation can be found [here](http://willtaylor.blog/rxjs-observables-hot-cold-explained/)) you can use [`groupBy`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/groupby.html) operator to group by the property.

For example:

```js
source$
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(history => Object.entries(history)),
    groupBy(([key]) => key),
    mergeMap(group => {
      return zip(
        of(group.key),
        group.pipe(
          mergeMap(([_, values]) => values),
          toArray()
        )
      );
    }),
    toArray(),
    map(entries => Object.fromEntries(entries))
  )
  .subscribe(fullHistory => console.log(fullHistory));
```

Where `source$` is your incoming history, the full source code can be found in [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-qnexkn?devtoolsheight=60) stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

Update your scan function to be

```
(acc, val) => {
  // Merge data by hand (not done already)
  Object.keys(val).forEach(key => {
    if (acc[key]) {
      acc[key] = [ ...val[key], ...acc[key] ];
    } else {
      acc[key] = val[key];
    }
  });
  return acc;
}
```